# pusher-client gem throwing 2 for 1 error with Presence-Channels

Tags: ruby, pusher

The pusher-client rubygem works fine when subscribing to Public Channels, but it's throwing "ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)" when I try to subscribe to a Presence or Private Channel. Does this happen for anyone else?

```
module PusherClientTest

  require 'pusher-client'

  PusherClient.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
  options = { :secret => '12345' }
  socket = PusherClient::Socket.new("54321", options)
  USER_ID = 1

  socket.subscribe('presence-TestChannel', USER_ID)

  socket.bind('remark') do |data|
    puts data
  end

  socket.connect
end
```

#### Results in:

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > PusherClientTest
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
  from /Users/Dev/Sites/test_app/app/models/pusher_client_test.rb:16:in `subscribe'
  from /Users/Dev/Sites/test_app/app/models/pusher_client_test.rb:16
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `load_file'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:405:in `load_file'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:285:in `require_or_load'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing_not_from_s3_library'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/aws-s3-0.6.2/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:206:in `const_missing'
  from /Users/Dev/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02@test_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
  from (irb):1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git URL to the pusher-client repo needs to be specified in order to subscribe to presence & private Channels. It appears as though the published pusher-client gem hasn't been updated with the latest commits to the repo.

```
gem 'pusher-client', :git => "git://github.com/logankoester/pusher-client.git"
```

Further to this, specifying a fork of the main repo will enable :user_info options to be passed across in the subscription:

```
gem 'pusher-client', :git => "git://github.com/agileanimal/pusher-client.git"
```